# Is [code-challenge] necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags

Isn't [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) going to be applicable to all questions? Therefore, shouldn't we delete it and related tags?

Comment: I thinks, it's unuseful tag. Maybe we need to classify, which goals can be in questions and follow this classification, like: `codegolf`, `complexity`, `memory-usage`. Sometimes mix 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: @Nakilon Yes, I'm thinking the same. Does anyone know if it's possible to require one of a set of tags like meta sites require one of {discussion, bug, support}?

Comment: also we almost forgot `research` or smth like it, meaning *I don't want your code, I want ideas, links to scientific materials*.

Comment: Where does [Lorem Ipsum Compressor](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2380/761) fit then?

Answer (score 7):

No!  Do not delete it!  I did not commit to this site to practice writing as illegible code as I can to trivial problems.  I committed to this site to practice coming up with practical solutions to difficult problems.

Consider using `code-golf` for problems where being as terse as you possibly can is the challenge.  Consider using `coding-challenge` where the challenge is in actually coding a solution.

Comment: I read `coding-challenge` as including "coming up with practical solutions to difficult problems". It's a challenge to solve the problem that involves coding. How do you interpret it? (BTW, I [fully and 100% support scope growth beyond just code golf](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5/site-title-and-domain))

Answer (score 4):

Agree. I think tags like `code-challenge` and `code-golf` are more or less redundant for this site.

Comment: Right now [code-golf] is redundant, but *if* (and I'm going to answer a lot of questions like this :P) we widen scope then it will serve a purpose. However, however we move scope I don't see any on-topic questions *not* being [code-challenge] questions.

Comment: @marcog: True, though, I expect code golf to comprise at least 50% of posts, regardless, so, such a tag is probably still mostly content-free.

Comment: If it's that much (I really can't predict) then I'm less sure how to handle the distinction. Questioners should have an easy way to identify code golfs, without saying "this is a code golf". If >50% of questions are code golf I can foresee many questioners forgetting to tag [code-golf]. I guess we'll see how this evolves over time.

Comment: @marcog: Indeed, play by ear. :-)

Comment: So the question is now, do we delete these superfluous tags?

Comment: @marcog: Not yet. Once the pro tempore moderators are appointed, it'll be easy for them to, if indeed that's still the direction the site is going.

Comment: Definitely play it by ear but I think your benchmark is off.  Only if 100% of Questions were code-golf would that tag become superfluous.  The fact that > 50% are code-golf has zero bearing in my opinion on the usefulness of the code-golf tag.

Answer (score 2):

The area51 brief said something like code-golf *and* programming puzzles. I think there will probably be some nice programming puzzles that aren't really fun to golf, but then how to choose a correct answer? :)

Comment: See http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5/site-title-and-domain and http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-questions-from-google-code-jam-topcoder-etc-on-topic Somehow that got lost in the launch of the beta, but we're discussing bringing it back.