# What's our policy on tags?

Tags: discussion, policy, tags

There are a lot of questions now that could be tagged: "sudoku", "sorting", "maze" etc.

Should we tag them?

What is the current policy on tagging? Tag everything that appears thrice or more? Tag at-will?

Answer (score 7):

We want an end state where we get things tagged by

- [Type of game/puzzle/challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/should-the-code-golf-tag-be-blacklisted/155#155) (i.e [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), and other that seem good (I have an irrational prejudice against [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling), but if we must...))
- Rule variations (this is [language-agnostic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) and/or [language specific tags would live](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/132/78))
- General topics to help users pick posts in domains that interest them. Things like:

  - [Joey's](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146/whats-our-policy-on-tags/157#157) [maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maze)
  - [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) for things like the many ascii figure problems LiraNuna posted on Stack Overflow
  - [word-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-puzzle) for things like crossword and hangman
  - [pattern-matching](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern-matching) for regexp engines and the current [glob question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/467/78)
  - [simulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation)
  - [game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)
  - [data-structure](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structure) for things like [Martin's binary tree question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/478/free-a-binary-tree)
  - [path-finding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-finding)
  - [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)
  - and so on

The biggest problem is that until we've been at this for a while we won't know what the categories are. So, we should encourage pretty free tagging for a while, and then start using the synonym mechanism and editing to bring the outliers into conformance with the practice that develops.

---

**Edit:** I've started a campaign to add descriptive tags to as many just-tagged-code-golf type questions as I can. Help would be appreciated, as would review of my tagging choices.

In this process, I have [already](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1299/78) invented [three](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repeated-transformation) new [tags](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/252/78). Those would be particularly good candidates for review.

Answer (score 2):

I think as long as a tag describes a *class* of problems we can leave them. `maze` for example could mean maze-generation, maze-solving in the general case as well as more specific tasks and thus (in future) could be a useful tag.