# Are "one line" problems distinct from code golf, and if so what rules apply?

Tags: discussion, policy, tags, rules, contest-type

[How to write a single-line password generator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1360/78) asks for a solution in "one line".

It seems to me that this is *potentially* a different class of challenge from [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), and for the nonce I've tagged it [one-liner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-liner).

What say ye?

- Is this a different challenge?
- If so, how do we define *"one line"*? (Note that this will have to be sensitive to the differences between languages...)
- How does this interact with languages that prescribe a certain amount of scaffolding (like c requires `main`), or traditionally don't have a single command invocation from the command line?

Comment: In some languages, every program can be considered "one line".

Comment: @Peter: Yep, and some historical "one liner" contests have used arbitrary definitions. There was a apple ][ magazine that ran one which used "256 bytes" and also accepted submissions in assembly (since there was an assembler in the firmware).

Comment: *"What say you?"*, assuming you're going for something Denethor-ish. Also, I don't see anything wrong with `int main(){int n=42;while(n--)std::cout<<"You've got a virus.\n";return(0);}`

Answer (score 3):

[one-liner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-liner) is fine in my opinion.

As to what constitutes a one-liner, in languages that have a concept of statements, that's straightforward: the whole program should fit into one statement. (Scaffolding does not count as statements.)

In languages that don't have a concept of statement, then it gets pretty blurry. :-(